# Change transition time on onmouseover and onmouseout?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my HTML

```
<img class="logo" src="css/images/logo.png" align="center"    onmouseover="this.src='css/images/logohov.png'" onmouseout="this.src='css/images/logo.png'"> </img>
```

Is there a way I can change the transition time? I've added transition:all 0.3s ease; to the class logo but it doesnt do anything.

Thanks

Comment: That's because you're changing the `src`, not transitioning between two states.

Comment: Is there anything I can add to the code to change the transition? If not is there any jQuery/javascript tutorials that can show me how it can be done?

Comment: why this question is tagged as html and css? seems to be a js question...

Answer (score 2):

I had luck just adding

```
-webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
```

to my css for a class on a  tag and it effected the transition time for the onmouseover and onmouseout (not using any :hover css).

PS in order for the onmouseover and onmouseout to effect the text inside the  tag I had to put the  tag for my link around the entire button, instead of inside.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You are changing src attribute which can not be used with transition property,
even though you used content property of css then also it can not be used with transition, instead try two img tags, and hide one and show another with transition on hover.

[Here](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/) are some examples

Answer (score 0):

Transition property works only when you change a **CSS property**, in your example you changing an **HTML attribute**.

Try something like this:

```
<div class="logo" align="center" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundImage=\"url('css/images/logohov.png')\"" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundImage=\"url('css/images/logo.png')\""> </div>
```