# Add fade transition to onmouseout and onmouseover

Tags: html, css, onmouseover, onmouseout

I have an onmouseover and onmouseout image in my html. And it totally does its job. What I do still struggle with is adding a transition to the onmouse stuff so it doesn't change so quickly. I would like it to fade over into the other picture when you hover over the picture. Is something like this possible?

This person did something like that but it didn't work for me :(  :
[[Change transition time on onmouseover and onmouseout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26298664/change-transition-time-on-onmouseover-and-onmouseout])

Check my code and please help me if there is a simple solution. Best would be without java script...

```html
<html>
    <body>
          <div class="startpageicons">
            <div class="icongestaltung">   
              <img src="images/startpageicon_draw.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/startpageicon_gestaltungunddesign.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/startpageicon_draw.png'" style="transition: -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
transition: all .3s ease-in-out;">
            </div>
      </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please use a web image instead. Your "images/startpageicon_draw.png" won't show up in snippet.

Comment: do you prefer a pure css solution or a jQuery solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the `src` of an image won't trigger css `transition`. Here is a pure css solution you can try. You can use a `div` as the container and set the `background-image` on hover.

```css
.icongestaltung {
  background: url(http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/orange/stackoverflow-6-xxl.png) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;

  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;

  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.icongestaltung:hover {
  background-image: url("http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/gray/stackoverflow-xxl.png");
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div class="startpageicons">

    <div class="icongestaltung"></div>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```